# javax.mail.MessagingExcep tion: Can't send command to SMTP host; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, java

In jdk1.4 I can send mail, but when i try to send mail using jdk1.6 I get the below exception.

```
My Working Environment.
========================
1.OS       :  windwos 2008
2.JAVA     :  JDK1.6
3.Mail Api :  java mail1.4
4.Email    :  gmail
5.smtp port:  465 or 587
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingExcep
tion: Can't send command to SMTP host;
nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
    at SendMailTLS.main(SendMailTLS.java:47)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1365)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1353)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:794)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:33
6)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:258)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:137)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:86)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:150)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
    at SendMailTLS.main(SendMailTLS.java:42)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the lates version of JDK?
Could you provide source code which not working?
Please, show the output from mail code:

- System.out.println("Java version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
- System.out.println("Ext dirs: "  +System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs"));

Comment: Hi i am working on this example  [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: i checked the above line it is showing 'java version : 1.6.0-rc
Ext Dirs : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\
lib\ext' and i checked with jdk 1.4 too it showing the ext Dirs path 'Ext Dirs : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\j2re1.4.2_12\lib\ext' only

Comment: Ok, and what about jars in your classpath, did you added javaee.jar into it (if was added, please, remove it)? For excample start, jars from this archive is enough - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.5-oth-JPR (mail.jar and jars from lib folder)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. i find out the mistake which i have done. i wrongly replaced some jars like sun_jceprovider.jar ,dnsns.jar,localedata.jar from jre1.4 to jre1.6.